# Is it possible to implement Lazy Logic using WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a DataObject, which can be viewed as a tree:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeDataContract
{
    [DataMember]
    private SomeCollection collection;
    public SomeCollection Collection
    {
        get
        {
            if (collection == null)
            { 

            }
        }
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract]
public class SomeCollection : List<SomeDataContract>
{
}
```

I do not need to download the whole tree :)

Comment: I think you could specify in you WCF how much data you want back...

Comment: where does the lazy come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you're asking for a mechanism where WCF returns a place holder object and it further retrieves the real data from the server as it is being used on the client side (analogous to `Lazy<T>`). If so, the answer is no, WCF doesn't provide such a mechanism directly.

However, you can implement some laziness yourself, and make further calls on the client side to retrieve the objects as needed. For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeDataContract
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Id {get ; set;}
}
```

If you're using proxy generation, it will generate the `SomeDataContract` as a partial class on the client side. So you can extend it to add a `Children` property:

```
public partial class SomeDataContract
{
   private IEnumerable<SomeDataContract> _children;
   public IEnumerable<SomeDataContract> Children
   {
       if(_children == null)
       {
           // call the WCF service, assuming such a method exists... 
           _children = GetChildren(this.Id);
       }

       return _children;
   }
}
```